# Formatting time properly from milliseconds

Tags: java, android, time, format

I am timing an event like this:

```
seconds = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
// Something happens here
time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - seconds;
```

and then I have attempted to format it:

```
String Time = String.format("%d min, %d sec",
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time) -
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time)));
```

and the results don't make any sense, the minutes are thousands but the seconds seem to be normal numbers. What is the proper way to format the time?

Comment: You should either use the exact value given by `System.currentTimeMillis()` without any intermediate calculations or convert value in `seconds` (which is already converted from milliseconds to seconds) into minutes.

Comment: Also note that when you call `System.currentTimeMillies()` twice, the value will be different each time.

Comment: I am using 2 values of `System.currentTimeMillies()` because I want to time something by using the difference

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis()%1000;
long seconds = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)%60;
long minutes = (System.currentTimeMillis()/(60*1000))%60;
long hours = (System.currentTimeMillis()/(60*60*1000));
```

Leave out whatever parts you don't want and remove the modulus from the highest one you do.